# How do i remove a team from the dropdown for the next dropdown round?

Tags: javascript

I am working on an app on code.org and I am stuck in generating a tournament-like app. I have data tables for the teams available to select and afterwards the team selected. I am trying to remove the team selected from the teams available list but removeItems only uses numbers and positions. The coding language is HTML and here is the area of the code in which I wish to be able to continue in. I am trying to get record.oa minus the record.ou.

```
   createRecord("OpponentAvailable", {oa:(getProperty("dropdown2", "options"))}, function(record) {
         console.log(record.oa);
         onEvent("dropdown2", "change", function( ) {
       createRecord("OpponentUsed", {ou:(getProperty("dropdown2", "text"))}, function(record) {
              console.log(record.ou);
              removeItem(record.oa, record.ou);
            });
         });

     });
   });
 });
}
```

Comment: Please check out: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you're looking for, but this might be easier to solve using React.

Here is an example:

```js
/**
 * We've included React through <script> HTML tags. Usually you would do this:
 * 
 * import React from 'react'
 * import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
 */

/**
 * Some "shortcuts" to things we'll use.
 */
const { Fragment, useState } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

/**
 * List our teams in an array.
 */
const teamNames = [
  "Besaid Aurochs",
  "Luca Goers",
  "Al Bhed Psyches",
  "Ronso Fangs",
  "Guado Glories",
  "Kilika Beasts",
];

/**
 * A <select> that excludes a given team name.
 */
const Selector = ({ id, value, unassigned, exclude, callback }) => {
  const options = unassigned
    .filter((team) => team !== exclude)
    .map((team) => (
      <option key={team} value={team}>
        {team}
      </option>
    ));

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <select
        className="form-control"
        id={id}
        value={value}
        onChange={callback}
      >
        <option value="" disabled>
          Select a team
        </option>
        {options}
      </select>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

/**
 * A <table> that shows fixtures we've created.
 */
const FixtureTable = ({ fixtures }) => {
  const fixtureRows = fixtures.map((fixture) => {
    return (
      <Fragment key={Math.random()}>
        <tr>
          <td>{fixture.homeTeam}</td>
          <td>{fixture.awayTeam}</td>
        </tr>
      </Fragment>
    );
  });
  return (
    <table className="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Home</th>
          <th scope="col">Away</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{fixtureRows}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

/**
 * Our app, which reacts when we interact with the form
 */
const App = () => {
  const [unassigned, setUnassigned] = useState(teamNames); // Array of available teams.
  const [homeTeam, setHomeTeam] = useState(""); // Current value of <select id="homeTeam">.
  const [awayTeam, setAwayTeam] = useState(""); // Current value of <select id="awayTeam">.
  const [fixtures, setFixtures] = useState([]); // An array of fixtures.

  /**
   * When we use a <select>, its value is stored in "homeTeam" or "awayTeam"
   */
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case "homeTeam":
        setHomeTeam(event.target.value);
        break;
      case "awayTeam":
        setAwayTeam(event.target.value);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  /**
   * When we submit the form:
   * 
   * - a fixture is added to the "fixture" array.
   * - the <select> values are reset.
   */
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setFixtures([
      ...fixtures,
      {
        homeTeam,
        awayTeam,
      },
    ]);
    setUnassigned(
      unassigned.filter((team) => {
        return team !== homeTeam && team !== awayTeam;
      })
    );
    setHomeTeam("");
    setAwayTeam("");
  };

  /**
   * Show our form and table.
   */
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Add fixtures</h1>
        <p className="lead">Choose teams below.</p>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group row">
            <label htmlFor="homeTeam">Home side</label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <Selector
                id="homeTeam"
                value={homeTeam}
                unassigned={unassigned}
                exclude={awayTeam}
                callback={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group row">
            <label htmlFor="awayTeam">Away side</label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <Selector
                id="awayTeam"
                value={awayTeam}
                unassigned={unassigned}
                exclude={homeTeam}
                callback={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group row">
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                Add fixture
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <FixtureTable fixtures={fixtures} />
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

/**
 * Render our app to the DOM.
 */
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Set fixtures</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="root" role="main" class="container"></main>
</body>

</html>
```